# I can create new humans and clone them, what to do with the old ones?

Tags: creature-design

My plan is to repopulate the world with people 2.0

The ideal thing would be to sterilise all old humans and wait till they die out.

Except humanity 2.0 is still developing whilst the old world is already outnumbering me, any plan I initiate, they have more resources to stop it.
If I drop a virus that kills all humans, some will survive anyway, the rich will hide and not get infected.
If I release a virus that sterilises everyone, they will use sperm and ovary banks or simply clone sperm cells.

My goal is to eventually have a planet with 0 old humans, only cloned ones.

My cloned humans lack genitalia, live indefinitely, consume less water and less food, have higher musclular power output and are shorter, to be precise 1650 millimeters.

Their bones are hollow and structured like dinosaur bones to be lighter and stronger at the same time.

Cloned humans are more instinctive, old humans need to do manual calculation for a lot of things like math, music and art.

But old humans have proven to be able to do a lot of automatic subconscious calculations like hearing, seeing, standing without losing balance.

New humans can also for example calculate academic level equations with the same ease a newborn baby calculates the difference between up and down.

Comment: @Draft85 I didn't mention anything about the story, anything about any specific character involved.

Comment: So your question is really just "how do I kill all the humans I don't want"?

Comment: 'My goal is...'. Please clarify: Whose goal is this? Story-teller, demiurg/god, member of 'government of the world'? Demiurg could cast the Great Flood while secret organization will need long plan. And story-teller could just say 'some centuries later...'

Answer (score 4):

#### How do you slowly reduce the human population to 0 without them fighting back? A high UBI.

There's a [wikipedia page explaining how to do this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_and_fertility), most notable is this graph:

[image]

The conclusion is pretty obvious - once you get out of poverty, birth rate tends to plumet quickly below 2 children per woman. Once it's below 2 children per woman, the human race will slowly die out.

So use your resources from humanity 2.0 to lift living standards on Earth for humanity 1.0. Give everyone a decent Universal Basic Income, which is when the government gives everyone money, ideally unconditionally.

Andrew Yang in the USA Presidential 2020 Election wanted a UBI of \$12,000 USD per year per American citizen - that's not quite enough. I'd be looking at least at \$40,000 per year, but for safety you probably want to give up to \$80,000 per year seems to be sure enough to guarantee a population decline.

At 40k, you're looking at \$$2.8 \cdot 10^{14}$ 280 trillion dollars. Per year. Not a small amount, but if your creating a new human race you're obviously in possession of some means to create wealth.

Don't stop there - basically say yes to every reasonable welfare policy. Make sure everyone on the planet has fresh water. Replace every dangerous, slave-like, or exploited worker with a robot, and then give them a UBI. Give free and accessible birth control and abortion planet wide - make being anti-choice a crime. Replace every undesirable job with a robot - people only do the jobs they want, if any.

Stop every war if you can - you want everyone safe, happy, relaxed, and living upper-middle class lives free from debt, while robots make all the things, for no payment and provide the wealth for humanity.

A century later small towns will start to be abandoned. A few centuries later cities will start to shrink - buildings that are demolished will be replaced with smaller ones, or more spacious living.

After maybe 500 years, medium towns will be empty.

After a 1000 years, small countries will be empty.

Every 12 generations at 1.8 children per woman will reduce the population to a quarter of what it was. Every 48 generations it will reduce the population to 1/1000th of what it was.

1200 years the human race will be 7 million strong.

2400 years the human race will be 7 thousand strong.

3600 years the human race will be able to fit in a minibus.

Comment: There are two problems with this:  where will you get the actual money, and what will it buy, given that many people will opt out of working and so producing things to buy?  And what about the anomalies?  Even prosperous people sometimes have ten children, and that's the way to take over the world by outbreeding.

Comment: @ Mary. 1) Will it into existence with accounting tricks within a bank - in line with MMP philosophy, and 2) as discussed in the answer, you've replaced all the exploited workers of the world with robots making things - they make things - and better than we can. So much so the GDP of earth grows from the efficiency gain. Surely the context of this question implies a little bit of future tech....

Comment: I like this. "Help them thrive to death".

Comment: You will want to dominate the news media during the next 3600 years to keep the dwindling 1.0 population off the public radar.  It is all to easy (and fun) for the 1.0 humans to reverse the population decline if they are aware of it.  The media could also be used to promote highly dangerous sports and hobbies such as sky diving.  If you can  increase the accidental death rate of human 1.0s a bit, you might shave a thousand years off of the transition period and trade in the minibus for a two-seat sports car.

Comment: There are plenty of people fighting against UBI.

Comment: Also who says the fertility rate will remain that low as the population drops? I suppose you will replace them with Humans 2 so that it appears the population is not dropping? (Tangential: this is basically the fear white supremacists have about replacement...)

Answer (score 4):

### Make them ask to be Replaced:

DON'T tell the humans what you're doing! Humans 2.0 are biological androids, who work for cheap and do a better job. Now you have the rich on your side. They'll BANKROLL your cause, and support the laws you need to phase out humans.

Now make hyper-libertarian laws about property ownership, welfare, and human rights. Wait, the rich will do that for you. If they are convinced 2.0's are obedient enough, they may even insist on them having voting rights (giving them motive to expand 2.0 production as much as possible).

Humans have a right to nothing they don't pay for, unless they are voluntarily sterilized to stop being a burden on society (their choice). Your 2.0's outcompete humans for jobs, and as income inequality expands, the rich own the land (so common folk can't even go "back to the soil" to raise food). Make the breadbaskets of the world into nature preserves to restore wildlife (and drive up food prices) 2.0's do all the work, and the government (i.e. the lackeys of the rich) deploys an ever growing army of 2.0's to uphold the law. If needed, CloneCorp (the public face of your movement) can intervene directly to buy land, lobby for laws, or start wars (as corporations have done in the past).

At least for a while, make reproductive versions of 2.0's with the genetic equivalent of CRISPR sperm and eggs, so any human mating with a 2.0 has a 2.0 child.

Once your 2.0's outnumber humans, assert that they are entitled to civil rights, and make them the 'champions' of the common man. Overthrow and nationalize the resources of the wealthy - after all, 2.0's are the bulk of the armed forces. Your 2.0's still control jobs, and they now have the votes to control laws. The rich have been displaced, and it's just a matter of time until your 2.0's replace humanity just as *Homo Sapiens sapiens* replaced *Homo Sapiens neanderthalis*.

- One of the things I like about this is that the clones, as "perfect" humans, are exempted from any deeply unethical behavior in this scenario. The burden of morality is placed on elites who are being manipulated. The clones are put in the role of an oppressed minority, and if the do end up doing anything unethical, they can use that as a justification. The last humans may even aske to be forgiven for what they did.

Answer (score 2):

> Except humanity 2.0 is still developing whilst the old world is already outnumbering me, any plan I initiate, they have more resources to stop it. If I drop a virus that kills all humans, some will survive anyway, the rich will hide and not get infected. If I release a virus that sterilises everyone, they will use sperm and ovary banks or simply clone sperm cells.

Who cares what the rich do. If only the super-rich are able to hide in bunkers and survive, that's too few people to rebuild human civilization if they are competing against your new humans. Most of the super-rich's power comes from non-tangible assets that are only valuable in a capitalistic economy where you have a large number of consumers buying product. A claim to land or resources means nothing if you do not have the military force to back it up, and the claim of some rich coot coming from a bunker that they own some area is worthless.

On top of that, all you need to do then is send your armies of human 2.0 out and systematically kill whoever is left. Easiest way to do this would be to indoctrinate them so they have a deep-seated hatred towards old humanity and see them as subhuman. The surviving bunkers of humanity will be super easy to spot because they will be the only areas not controlled by you that are using electricity or other artificial technology, and because they're worried about a disease, not a genocidal race of ubermensch wiping out every last one of their kind, they won't think to hide their emissions. You'll need to keep this hatred and dehumanization up if you want to make sure isolated patches of old humanity are wiped out when rediscovered, or if some of your new humans start interbreeding with the survivors and introducing old human genes into your population. Yes it's a horrible dystopian ideal that results in immense human suffering, but your question asks how to commit *genocide* to impose a genetically homogenous ethnostate, what did you expect?

On top of *that*, assuming you are talking about a near-modern setting, technology hasn't advanced enough to allow us to clone humans. Even with our modern level of technology, we would require human women to act as surrogate mothers or invent some sort of artificial womb technology (which we do not have right now). So if you wiped out 99%+ of all humans, the only way old humans would be able to reproduce is the old-fashioned way.

Comment: They can't interbreed, I said clones do not have genitals. Plus artificial wombs are a thing of the 2010s.

Comment: @Rhea No, they aren't. [The closest anyone has come has been to remove three month old near-term lamb fetuses from their mother and keep them on life support for about a month](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15112). A third of them died and none of them were allowed to be fully delivered to see if they turned out okay. A true fertilization-to-delivery system for lambs, let alone humans, remains out of our reach.

Answer (score 1):

You present your 2.0's as a great new thing for everyone to have!

Make them cheap enough that just about anyone can buy one, gift others to poor people in charity. If need be you can put in some restrictions on how many you can own to prevent large economical upsets and subsequent hate towards your new humans.

As the human populace embraces them and wants more the population of 2.0's will grow. Then at some point you have enough to don your cowled robe and contact all 2.0's on the world and tell them "execute order 66".

Humans aren't that interested in enacting murder and violence despite what we get taught. Your 2.0's won't have that problem. The first step is simple: hide foodsupplies and contaminate many fresh water sources. Then they can start killing humans with anything they cab find. From simple kitchen knives to grabbing a truck and creating horrible accidents on the roads to grabbing the military hardware and going to town with it, the suddeness of the violent murderspree of a few million to billion 2.0 humans while food shortages and water problems hit the population should be enough to kill the old population.

Answer (score 1):

As in the [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run) and [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run_(film)) *Logan's Run*, after reaching a certain age, the "old" people are killed.

In the novel, the age was 21. In the film it was 30.

In the film, everyone was told they would be "reborn" when they were 30 years old by undergoing the carousel ritual - a spectator event where they were all killed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make them slaves, soldiers, test subjects, or use their body parts for transplants. You could try sterilizing them all and burn the sperm/egg banks. To kill them, you could get rid of/pollute food or water sources because humans 2.0 don't need as much.